# Using XPath on single node returns elements in all nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I am parsing an XML doc that looks something like this:

```
<MyBook>
   <title>Favorite Poems</title>
   <issn>123-456</issn>
   <pages>45</pages>
</MyBook>
<MyBook>
   <title>Chocolate Desserts</title>
   <issn>654-098</issn>
   <pages>100</pages>
</MyBook>
<MyBook>
   <title>Jabberwocky</title>
   <issn>454-545</issn>
   <pages>19</pages>
</MyBook>
```

I use xpath to pull out the MyBook nodes and iterate through them like so:

```
xmldoc.xpath("//MyBook").each do |node|
   mytitle=node.xpath("//title").text
   puts mytitle
end
```

the output looks like this:

```
Favorite PoemsChocolateDessertsJabberwocky
Favorite PoemsChocolateDessertsJabberwocky
Favorite PoemsChocolateDessertsJabberwocky
```

as if the node is really the whole xmldoc.  However if I print out the node within the iterator, each time it is what I expect, just a single MyBook node.  I need to be able to pull out the child nodes from each node successively, not all of the same kind of child node from the whole document. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

When you use `//title` this searches for all `<title>` elements starting at the root of the document. Use either simply `title` to find child titles, or `.//title` if you want to find titles even if they are nested inside of other elements.

Comment: aha!  Thank you very much.  So it doesn't matter that I am applying the xpath expression to a node?

Comment: Putting `/` or `//` at the front makes the XPath an absolute path. When you use those the XPath evaluator ignores the context node and starts at the document root.

Comment: @JohnKugelman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412067/use-nokogiri-xpath-to-select-root-and-children-matching-expression

Answer (score 0):

Remove the // from the title xpath expression.