# Use XPath to select root and children matching expression

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse some XML that looks kind of like:

```
<item name="item one">
    <other name="other name"/>
    <third />
</item>
<item name="item two">
    <other />
    <third />
</item>
```

I'm parsing over the items using Nokogiri like so:

```
xmldoc.xpath("//item").each do |node|
  node.xpath("//*[@name]") # Gives me *all* elements in the doc
  node.xpath(".//*[@name]") # Gives me child elements of the item
end
```

What expression can I use to get `[item, other]` from the first node as I iterate through?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your XML is not valid and your source code doesn't run. Don't ask us to write code just to test yours.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` at the beginning would make the XPath expression context-specific, use `@` to get the attributes, `@*` to get all attributes (wildcard):

```
node.xpath(".//*/@*")
node.xpath("@*")
```

And, getting all attributes of the current node as well as all attributes of all child nodes:

```
node.xpath(".//@*")
```

Comment: Is there one expression that would accomplish both lines at the same time? I want all attributes on the root or any child.

Comment: How would I modify it to get just all "name" attributes (ignoring other attributes)?

Comment: @karl try `./descendant-or-self::node()/@name`.

Comment: `.//@name` will work as well. `//` is shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it will work for you, but if you find nodes
you can use `node.name` to get `item` element, you can find all `other` and check if `.parent.name== 'item'`
see more here:
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet