# Assignment of XML to Ruby Class gone awry

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm assigning the results of an XPath search to a Ruby object, but the object seems to have a access to the whole original document, not just what I've assigned it.

This is a simplified example of what I'm experiencing:

```
<message>
  <person>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <organs>
       <heart>yes</heart>
       <lungs>yes</lungs>
       <ears>yes</ears>
    </organs>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Jim</name>
    <organs>
       <heart>yes</heart>
       <lungs>no</lungs>
       <ears>yes</ears>
    </organs>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Fred</name>
    <organs>
       <heart>yes</heart>
       <lungs>maybe</lungs>
       <ears>yes</ears>
    </organs>
  </person>
</message>
```

Then I have a class that is designed to hold the information for section:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :person 

  def initialize(info)
    @person = info
  end

  def get_lungs
    return @person.xpath("//organs/lungs").first.content
  end
end
```

Then the code to process the message and assign the "persons" to the Person class and perform further processing:

```
message = doc.xpath("message")
message.xpath('person').each do |p|
  prsn = Person.new(p)
  queue.push("person" => prsn)  
end

loop ...
  work - queue.pop
  per = work['person']
  lungs = per.get_lungs  
end
```

The problem is, `lungs` is always "yes".  And in the `get_lungs` function, it is actually possible to loop through all the values in the original message, even though the Person object should only contain one person section from the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each document node still has access to the whole document (See [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#document-instance_method)).
Even though it looks like you're only passing a `person` node, this node still references the  whole document!

Also, `//` [scans the whole document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3569982/6419007), so

```
@person.xpath("//organs/lungs").first
```

doesn't depend on `@person` and always returns the first `lung`. You could also use [`at_xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at_xpath-instance_method) instead of `xpath.first`.

Just remove `//` and it should work :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(message)

doc.xpath('//person').each do |person|
  p person.at_xpath("organs/lungs").content
end
```

It outputs :

```
"yes"
"no"
"maybe"
```

Comment: Eric - thanks for your answer.  But I'm still really confused.  Given this code:  `code` message.xpath('person').each do |p|
  prsn = Person.new(p)
  queue.push("person" => prsn)  
end `code` - how is that each "prsn" can see the whole message when only the prsn is being assigned to the object?

Comment: Updated. `prsn.document` is still accessible from your Person instance.

Comment: Thanks you!  I can't say I fully understand why it works this way, but your solution worked.  I up-voted your answer by my rep is too small to make it show.

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: It's very rarely required to use `xpath`, `css`, `at_css` or `at_xpath`, and instead usually `search` or `at` is sufficient. Nokogiri is usually able to determine whether a selector is CSS or XPath. In years of writing Nokogiri code I've only had to use the explicit method name once.

Comment: Thanks. So I could replace `xpath` with `search` and `at_xpath` with `at`?